# How to add support of bit-banging i2c bus in u boot code for MIPS Board

Tags: linux, mips, i2c, u-boot

I have one **MIPS board AR9341** in which I want to add support of **bit-banging i2c** bus from u boot itself not from kernel.

I have also two **GPIOs** which are free and can be used for SDA and SCL Pin.

I have also read some documents as well as User Guide about how to add support bit-banging i2c bus in u boot but not getting proper idea.

Does any one has any document or idea about how to add support of bit-banging i2c bus using GPIOs from u boot?

Please help me if any one has idea about that as soon as possible.

I have tried to set and clear two **GPIOs** with two **LEDs** from u boot and it works fine without any issue. Now I want to connect those two GPIos as **SDA** and **SCL** line for software bit-banging.

Does any one has idea about how to configure that **GPIOs** as **SDA** and **SCL** Line in u boot code itself?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to get an example of bit-banging the I²C Master protocol listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) and port (adapt) it to your MCU hardware.

Below is an example of bit-banging the I²C protocol as an I²C master. The example is written in pseudo C. It illustrates all of the I²C features described before (clock stretching, arbitration, start/stop bit, ack/nack)

```
    // Hardware-specific support functions that MUST be customized:
#define I2CSPEED 100
void I2C_delay() { volatile int v; int i; for (i=0; i < I2CSPEED/2; i++) v; }
bool read_SCL(void); // Set SCL as input and return current level of line, 0 or 1
bool read_SDA(void); // Set SDA as input and return current level of line, 0 or 1
void clear_SCL(void); // Actively drive SCL signal low
void clear_SDA(void); // Actively drive SDA signal low
void arbitration_lost(void);

bool started = false; // global data
void i2c_start_cond(void) {
  if (started) { // if started, do a restart cond
    // set SDA to 1
    read_SDA();
    I2C_delay();
    while (read_SCL() == 0) {  // Clock stretching
      // You should add timeout to this loop
    }
    // Repeated start setup time, minimum 4.7us
    I2C_delay();
  }
  if (read_SDA() == 0) {
    arbitration_lost();
  }
  // SCL is high, set SDA from 1 to 0.
  clear_SDA();
  I2C_delay();
  clear_SCL();
  started = true;
}

void i2c_stop_cond(void){
  // set SDA to 0
  clear_SDA();
  I2C_delay();
  // Clock stretching
  while (read_SCL() == 0) {
    // add timeout to this loop.
  }
  // Stop bit setup time, minimum 4us
  I2C_delay();
  // SCL is high, set SDA from 0 to 1
  if (read_SDA() == 0) {
    arbitration_lost();
  }
  I2C_delay();
  started = false;
}

// Write a bit to I2C bus
void i2c_write_bit(bool bit) {
  if (bit) {
    read_SDA();
  } else {
    clear_SDA();
  }
  I2C_delay();
  while (read_SCL() == 0) { // Clock stretching
    // You should add timeout to this loop
  }
  // SCL is high, now data is valid
  // If SDA is high, check that nobody else is driving SDA
  if (bit && read_SDA() == 0) {
    arbitration_lost();
  }
  I2C_delay();
  clear_SCL();
}

// Read a bit from I2C bus
bool i2c_read_bit(void) {
  bool bit;
  // Let the slave drive data
  read_SDA();
  I2C_delay();
  while (read_SCL() == 0) { // Clock stretching
    // You should add timeout to this loop
  }
  // SCL is high, now data is valid
  bit = read_SDA();
  I2C_delay();
  clear_SCL();
  return bit;
}

// Write a byte to I2C bus. Return 0 if ack by the slave.
bool i2c_write_byte(bool send_start,
                    bool send_stop,
                    unsigned char byte) {
  unsigned bit;
  bool nack;
  if (send_start) {
    i2c_start_cond();
  }
  for (bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
    i2c_write_bit((byte & 0x80) != 0);
    byte <<= 1;
  }
  nack = i2c_read_bit();
  if (send_stop) {
    i2c_stop_cond();
  }
  return nack;
}

// Read a byte from I2C bus
unsigned char i2c_read_byte(bool nack, bool send_stop) {
  unsigned char byte = 0;
  unsigned bit;
  for (bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
    byte = (byte << 1) | i2c_read_bit();
  }
  i2c_write_bit(nack);
  if (send_stop) {
    i2c_stop_cond();
  }
  return byte;
}
```

Then you will need **TO DO** all places commented in the code above where `1` or `0` is set on a proper GPIO, depends of which ones you choose on your device.

By the way, I've done this for MSP430 and it works.

Also you can find on the net implementations for a number of other MCUs and compare them, like these ones below, but I would begin with the code above.

- [PIC16](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en560799)

> ```
> #include "pic16lf1947.h"
> #include "PIC16_I2C_BITBANG.h"
> #include "xc.h"
>
>
>
> //....................................................................
> // This function generates an I2C Start Condition
> //....................................................................
> void i2c_start(void)
> {
> unsigned int i;
>
> SDA_TRIS = 1;                   // ensure SDA & SCL are high
> SCL = 1;
> SDA_TRIS = 0;                   // SDA = output
> SDA = 0;                        // pull SDA low
> for (i=0;i<2;i++) NOP();
> SCL = 0;                        // pull SCL low
> }
>
>
> //....................................................................
> // This function generates an I2C Stop Condition
> //....................................................................
> void i2c_stop(void)
> {
> unsigned int i;
>
> SCL = 0;                        // ensure SCL is low
> SDA_TRIS = 0;                   // SDA = output
> SDA = 0;                        // SDA low
> for (i=0;i<3;i++) NOP();
> SCL = 1;                        // pull SCL high
> SDA_TRIS = 1;                   // allow SDA to be pulled high
> for (i=0;i<3;i++) NOP();
> SCL=0;                          // ensure SCL is low
> }
>
>
> //.......................................................... AR9341..........
> // Outputs a bit to the I2C bus
> //....................................................................
> void bit_out(unsigned char data)
> {
> unsigned int i;
>
> SCL = 0;                        // ensure SCL is low
> SDA_TRIS=0;                     // configure SDA as an output
> SDA= (data>>7);                 // output the MSB
> for (i=0;i<2;i++) NOP();
> SCL = 1;                        // pull SCL high to clock bit
> for (i=0;i<3;i++) NOP();
> SCL = 0;                        // pull SCL low for next bit
> }
>
>
> //....................................................................
> // Inputs a bit from the I2C bus
> //....................................................................
> void bit_in(unsigned char *data)
> {
> unsigned int i;
>
> SCL = 0;                        // ensure SCL is low
> SDA_TRIS = 1;                   // configure SDA as an input
> SCL = 1;                        // bring SCL high to begin transfer
> for (i=0;i<3;i++) NOP();
> *data |= SDA;                   // input the received bit
> SCL = 0;                        // bring SCL low again.
> }
>
>
> //....................................................................
> // Writes a byte to the I2C bus
> //....................................................................
> unsigned char i2c_wr(unsigned char data)
> {
> unsigned char i;                // loop counter
> unsigned char ack;              // ACK bit
>
> ack = 0;
> for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)         // loop through each bit
>     {
>     bit_out(data);              // output bit
>     data = data << 1;           // shift left for next bit
>     }
>
> bit_in(&ack);                   // input ACK bit
> return ack;
> }
>
>
> //....................................................................
> // Reads a byte from the I2C bus
> //....................................................................
> unsigned char i2c_rd(unsigned char ack)
> {
> unsigned char i;                // loop counter
> unsigned char ret=0;            // return value
>
> for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)         // loop through each bit
>     {
>     ret = ret << 1;             // shift left for next bit
>     bit_in(&ret);               // input bit
>     }
>
> bit_out(ack);                   // output ACK/NAK bit
> return ret;
> }
>
>
> //.............................................................................
> //          Polls the bus for ACK from device
> //.............................................................................
> void ack_poll (unsigned char control)
> {
> unsigned char result=1;
>
> while(result)
>   {
>   i2c_start();            // generate Restart condition
>   result=i2c_wr(control); // send control byte (WRITE command)
>         }
>
> i2c_stop();                     // generate Stop condition
> }
> ```

- [AVR](http://codinglab.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/i2c-on-avr-using-bit-banging.html)

> ```
> // Port for the I2C
> #define I2C_DDR DDRD
> #define I2C_PIN PIND
> #define I2C_PORT PORTD
>
> // Pins to be used in the bit banging
> #define I2C_CLK 0
> #define I2C_DAT 1
>
> #define I2C_DATA_HI()\
> I2C_DDR &= ~ (1 << I2C_DAT);\
> I2C_PORT |= (1 << I2C_DAT);
> #define I2C_DATA_LO()\
> I2C_DDR |= (1 << I2C_DAT);\
> I2C_PORT &= ~ (1 << I2C_DAT);
>
> #define I2C_CLOCK_HI()\
> I2C_DDR &= ~ (1 << I2C_CLK);\
> I2C_PORT |= (1 << I2C_CLK);
> #define I2C_CLOCK_LO()\
> I2C_DDR |= (1 << I2C_CLK);\
> I2C_PORT &= ~ (1 << I2C_CLK);
>
> void I2C_WriteBit(unsigned char c)
> {
>     if (c > 0)
>     {
>         I2C_DATA_HI();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         I2C_DATA_LO();
>     }
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_HI();
>     delay(1);
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_LO();
>     delay(1);
>
>     if (c > 0)
>     {
>         I2C_DATA_LO();
>     }
>
>     delay(1);
> }
>
> unsigned char I2C_ReadBit()
> {
>     I2C_DATA_HI();
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_HI();
>     delay(1);
>
>     unsigned char c = I2C_PIN;
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_LO();
>     delay(1);
>
>     return (c >> I2C_DAT) & 1;
> }
>
> // Inits bitbanging port, must be called before using the functions below
> //
> void I2C_Init()
> {
>     I2C_PORT &= ~ ((1 << I2C_DAT) | (1 << I2C_CLK));
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_HI();
>     I2C_DATA_HI();
>
>     delay(1);
> }
>
> // Send a START Condition
> //
> void I2C_Start()
> {
>     // set both to high at the same time
>     I2C_DDR &= ~ ((1 << I2C_DAT) | (1 << I2C_CLK));
>     delay(1);
>
>     I2C_DATA_LO();
>     delay(1);
>
>     I2C_CLOCK_LO();
>     delay(1);
> }
>
> // Send a STOP Condition
> //
> void I2C_Stop()
> {
>     I2C_CLOCK_HI();
>     delay(1);
>
>     I2C_DATA_HI();
>     delay(1);
> }
>
> // write a byte to the I2C slave device
> //
> unsigned char I2C_Write(unsigned char c)
> {
>     for (char i = 0; i < 8; i++)
>     {
>         I2C_WriteBit(c & 128);
>
>         c <<= 1;
>     }
>
>     //return I2C_ReadBit();
>     return 0;
> }
>
>
> // read a byte from the I2C slave device
> //
> unsigned char I2C_Read(unsigned char ack)
> {
>     unsigned char res = 0;
>
>     for (char i = 0; i < 8; i++)
>     {
>         res <<= 1;
>         res |= I2C_ReadBit();
>     }
>
>     if (ack > 0)
>     {
>         I2C_WriteBit(0);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         I2C_WriteBit(1);
>     }
>
>     delay(1);
>
>     return res;
> }
> ```

Good luck!

Comment: @Rulsan Thanks for reply. How to add GPIO configuration with that SDA and SCL Pin in my board file in u-boot itself? Do you have any idea for that? It should be ioport based or io-memory based configuration for that software i2c bit-banging?

Comment: I don't know much about uboot but did you have previously simple access and control over any of GPIO lines,can you do before just simple thing like set `1` or `0` on chosen lines? Implementing this you at least should be sure that it your API (it's just simply one string of code in C or ASM) simply works - you can check it by measuring voltage on that pin by multimeter or watching the line by oscilloscope. Having this simple set of line controlling functions implemented and checked naturally you can rely on the pseudo C code above. Also you most likely to implement I/O direction switchers.

Comment: I am currently working on to set 1 or 0 to two free GPIOs from u boot code itself. Then I will try to add software bit-banging support with those two GPIOs as SDA and SCL line.

Comment: I have tried to control GPIOs from u-boot code itself and it works fine without any issue. I don't have idea about how to add software i2c support in u-boot level. Do you have any idea that ioport or iomemory is used to add support of i2c bit-banging in u-boot level?

Comment: Good, now include all the code provided and try to compile, resolve all compilation issues, if any, and implement hardware specific functions such as `bool read_SCL(void); 
bool read_SDA(void); 
void clear_SCL(void);
void clear_SDA(void);`